# Usage of IPInterfaceStatistics in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking to use this class

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPInterfaceStatistics
```

In a .NET 4.0 App. I am using BCL Portability Pack but it looks as though it is not there. Does anybody know of a way to achieve this or a library I can include?

Comment: BCL - the Microsoft compatibilty pack that allows you to Target .NET 4.5 Apps to .NET 4.0

Comment: So you mean Portable Class Libraries?

Comment: The portability pack is not a bandaid to bridge platform differences.  The underlying operating system api was changed in Vista, an explanation for why why it could be added to 4.5, it no longer supports XP.  And otherwise unavailable on other platforms so a lost cause in a PCL project.